# Spring MVC Custom Annotation implemetation

Tags: spring-mvc, custom-component

I have made one custom annotation using

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping .
```

It's working fine,sometimes it's looking costly as for all method call, control goes to Annotation implementation class. **I want the control will go to the implementation class only for those methods for which custom annotation has been declared. Can someone please tell how can I achieve that.**
I have done it as follows.

in web.xml :-

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
 <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in controller.xml :-

```
<bean id="myInterceptor" class="com.common.annotation.MyInterceptor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">  
 <property name="interceptors">  
    <list>  
         <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>  
     </list>  
 </property>  
</bean>
```

In Annotaion class : -

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
public @interface MyAnnotation {  
        boolean checkAuth() default true;  
    }
```

Use it as:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @MyAnnotation(checkAuth=true)
    public ModelAndView forUser() {........
```

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the custom interceptor you implemented to be called for methods that are annotated with `@MyAnnotation`?

Comment: Yes Niall, exactly I am looking for that.

Comment: Why do you consider the current method costly?

Comment: In our application most of the methods wouldn't use this annotation but for all of them run-time control will go to the implementation class. This is bother me costly and I want to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

You really have 2 options for implementing this in a generic way:

1. Interceptor
2. AOP

Using AOP you could use a pointcut that specifies your annotation, and create advice that contains your logic. If you use Spring AOP, this would extend only the methods that are annotated.

Something like this:

```
@Aspect
class MyAnnotationAspect {
    @Around(value="@annotation(org.sample.MyAnnotation)")
    public Object display(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation ) throws Throwable {
        if(myAnnotation.checkUser()) {
            // Auth logic goes here
        }
    }
}
```